# Meaning of 娘が心配しちゃいますので

Tags: meaning

「お礼に一杯おごろう。実は今日、給料が入ったんだ」

「そうですね、嬉しいお誘いなのですが……」

「……**娘が心配しちゃいますので**」

Context: The above two characters have been out for a while and the guy offers to treat her with his pay. She declines because:

1) Her daughter will be worried about her 
2) She is worried about her daughter

I believe its 1) as I think 心配なので　would have been used for the other meaning but I am unsure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, 娘が心配する means "(my) daughter is worried (about someone else)," whereas 娘が心配だ means "(I am) worried about (my) daughter". (**EDIT:** The latter expression using the (na-)adjective is in the same vein as [猫が好きだ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17857/5010) and 猫が欲しい)

So 娘が心配しちゃいますので in this dialog means "(If I go home late) My daughter will be worried about me, so... (I can't go with you)."