# Is it the easy way to remember to use が?

Tags: particle-は, particle-が

I come to my realization that I should use the particle が to introduce a new thing that a listener does not know about (and intend to know about). For example:

> トニー：このオープニングはいいですね。
>   ルーシー：トニーくんの言ったことに加えて、これが私の大好きなものです。

- Tony: This anime opening is good.
- Lucy: In addition to that, it is my favorite part. (particle が is used).

Tony is the listener, and he doesn't know the fact about Lucy. When Lucy says the fact, particle が is used, not particle は.

Particle が and は are very confusing. I hope someone will help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: `このが` should be こ**れ**が.

Comment: I found this write-up recently which is very similar to what you mention. It cleared a lot of things up for me. https://www.reddit.com/r/LearnJapanese/comments/6u2gaf/let_me_try_and_explain_%E3%81%AF_and_%E3%81%8C_for_you/

Comment: Do you want to emphasize this is the thing what you really wanted with "これが” rather than stating this is something like you really wanted with"これは”？

Comment: Simply that, if a speaker mentions a piece of information that the listener did not expect to hear at all, then the particle が is used.

Comment: For example, Tony knows that Lucy likes it, he did not expect that the anime opening is particularly Lucy's favorite.

Comment: Ah, if the information is new to the listener and the speaker wants to give the important information you can use case marker "が”. On the other hand, if the listener and the speaker know the information well you can use topic marker "は”　It might be detailed explanation http://www.nkc.u-tokyo.ac.jp/study_info/study_info01_04_j.html

Comment: I think it is easier to understand than above https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/17857/%E7%A7%81%E3%81%AF%E7%8C%AB%E3%81%8C%E5%A5%BD%E3%81%8D-and-%E7%8C%AB%E3%81%AF%E7%A7%81%E3%81%8C%E5%A5%BD%E3%81%8D?rq=1

Comment: Ah, if the information is new to the listener and the speaker wants to give the important information you can use case marker "が”. - Thank you for your direction, I will keep it in mind.

Comment: That is more than enough of an answer. Thank you again.

Comment: But I read the link in Shirlik's comment a little bit.I guess It explained the same thing really well.They break the particle "は and が" down and explained concisely in 6 situations. I think it explains the gist of it. So, if you haven't read it,  you should definitely have a look.

Comment: @Shirik The first 3 paragraphs in the article you introduced is really great. However, no.4, 5 and 6 are inaccurate so that you will eventually run into examples that don't get along with them.

Comment: That is way too complicated to learn if you all keep posting comments. I simply wanted an easy way to get the concept - I already explained all the information in details.

Comment: Thank you all for the discussion. The question should be closed. "kimi" was the one who answered the question.

Answer (score 2):

Since このオープニング is already introduced in the トニー's remark, you would use は and say これは私の大好きなものです unless there are other reasons.

When you say これが…大好きなもの, it implies that it's what ルーシー likes among several choices.

Comment: So in a word: is it the easy way to remember or not? ;-)

Comment: I don't know if it's easy, but it's inaccurate anyway.

Comment: I appreciate your time, it looks like that it is beyond what I could understand so I can say it is accurate. [すかし、私はありがとうと言うことができると思います。]