# 「が」(ga) vs 「は」(wa) when it comes to specifically "this" object / referring to self

Tags: particles, particle-は, particle-が, は-and-が

Learning particles and looking at `wa` vs `ga`. From what I have seen `wa` is the topic/general and `ga` is for the subject/specific.

I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=128&v=9J4FL1CbXTg) which had the following example:

> I like Van Gogh's paintings.
>
> Gohho no e ga suki desu.

I understand they are talking about Gogh's paintings specifically so they used `ga`, but since there isn't plurals in Japanese from what I have learned so far and `ga` was already used to refer to Gogh specifically and not a specific painting, how does one express the following?

> I like this Van Gogh painting.

Fumbling around with translators it appears the entire sentence changes to add `this` and `I` become the topic whereas before `I` was omitted.

> Watashi wa kono Gohho no e ga suki desu.

Still learning the basic sentence structures, but is that correct? Because I added `this/kono`, the entire sentence must change to include myself as the topic? I was expecting to just be able to place `kono` somewhere in the original sentence. When do I know I need to use `Watashi` instead of just `desu`?

Comment: If I understand correctly, your basis for asking the question comes from how machine translation handled various things you gave it? That's not a reliable way to discern anything about the language, unfortunately.

Comment: @Leebo Ah I know, but that's also why I asked the question to get clarification because I didn't trust it and thought there had to be a simpler way. I bought a text book and going through it, but I haven't hit the grammar sections yet and kinda went down the rabbit hole of learning sentence structure outside of it tonight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I figured out my confusion. Because `watashi` was omitted in the previous sentences I learned, I thought `desu` filled in the gap because I misunderstood what it meant in `TyCobb desu.`. The textbook automatically omitted `Watashi wa` so I thought `desu` referred to `I` in certain situations/contexts.

Upon further research, it is `to be, is/am` or used to end a sentence after a noun or adjective. This made me realize that `suki` in Japanese is a na-adjective or noun or both? Need to revisit that, but it's not a verb like it is in English.

So if what I have read is correct, this should be correct:

> Kono Gohho no e ga suki desu.

And if I understand writing (or at least typing and checking the chart) in hiragana correctly:

> このごっほのえがすきです。

Comment: Your final sentence is correct. This link may also help (or massively confuse you): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/17876/7944

Comment: @user3856370 Thanks a lot for the confirmation and the link.