# Difference between particles wa, ga and o with sukidesu

Tags: word-choice, usage, particles

What is the difference between these sentences, and their particle usage?

> - *watashi **wa** kore **ga** sukidesu*
> - *watashi **ga** kore **o** sukidesu*

I don't really understand the usage of these particles.

Comment: Related (duplicate?): http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4210/7810, http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3473/7810, http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4327/7810

Comment: Can you read hiragana and some kanji?

Comment: You really have to remember them. The second is wrong.

Comment: Yes, I can, Earthlin. I can read all hiragana, most katakana and some kanji.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. わたしはこれが好【す】きです。
>       Watashi wa kore ga sukidesu.

... is neutral and very basic "I like it". It's the most basic way to say "I like ～" in Japanese. See: [私は猫が好き and 猫は私が好き](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17857/5010)

> 2. わたし**が**これが好きです。
>       Watashi **ga** kore ga sukidesu.

This sentence uses exhaustive-listing *ga* described [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/22/5010). When someones asks "Who likes it (among those people)?" then this sentence would be the natural response. It's like saying "*I* like it" with emphasis on "I".

> 3. わたし**が**これ**を**好きです。
>       Watashi **ga** kore **o** sukidesu.

This is semantically the same as Sentence 2. In complex sentences, sometimes を can be used instead of が as if 好き were a normal verb. This phenomenon has been discussed several times on this site (see: [Why is を used in this situation? 私は先生がネコを好きだと思います](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4210/5010) and [Usage of ～を好き outside of embedded clauses](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/26005/5010) ). In your example, instead of saying が twice, you can replace the second が with を. According to [this article (in Japanese)](http://www.ritsumei.ac.jp/acd/cg/lt/rb/599/599pdf/higasiya.pdf) this happens more often in younger generations. But I think this one is grammatically exceptional, so I recommend you familiarize yourself with Sentences 1 and 2 first.

Comment: If I turn わたしがこれを好きです to わたしをこれが好きです, it means "this likes me". Is it possible for "わたしがこれが好きです" to mean "this likes me" also given the right context?

Comment: @firuvi An exhaustive-listing-ga normally comes at the beginning of the sentence. Even when the context clearly tells これ refers to a human, you usually have to say これが私が好きです ("*This* likes me") at least.