# Why is causative form used here?

Tags: grammar, causation

The following is an excerpt from a reply from my language partner:
アンドレアスさんの試みでは、対比させるには、例文が少し難しいと思います。

*For context:*
 I tried out a rather overcomplicated structure in passive voice because I wanted to see wether this is still grammatical/understandable or not. I also wrote down the same sentence in the active voice and I asked for her feedback.

Here are the 2 sentences (ridden with awful grammar):

passive voice:

> 例えば、チームのスパイ行為はチームにwhaleとsharkの言葉を選ばれるつもりだったら、「Fish, 2」という暗示を上げたらいいでしょう。この番号は代行者にスパイ行為が望言葉の分量を送ります。

Active voice:

> 例えば、チームのスパイ行為はチームがwhaleとsharkの言葉を選ぶつもりだったら、「Fish, 2」という暗示を上げたらいいでしょう。この番号は代行者にスパイ行為が望言葉の分量を送ります。

So, back to the sentence in question, here is my attempt at translation:
"Concerning your experiment, *? comparison ?* I think the example sentence is a bit difficult."

I don't know what to do with this causative verbform. I know it in context of sentences like these: 先生が学生に宿題をたくさんさせた。-> "The teacher made the students do lots of homework."
But in context of the sentence in question, I really have no idea how whoever has made whoever make a comparison xD 
I also don't really know what to make of this second は in 対比させるには

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/27907/dictionary-form-of-verb-followed-by-%e3%81%ab

Comment: I would guess that the causative means 'allow', so 'in order to allow comparison', but I'm not sure if you can use causative like that. Interesting question.

Comment: I believe she's saying 'It's might be too much to make you (expect you to) attempt to compare/contrast such difficult examples.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> アンドレアスさんの試みでは、対比させるには、例文が少し難しいと思います。
>   I think your example sentence is a bit too difficult (for me) to make a (good) comparison (between passive voice and active voice).

So you're mainly interested in voices (passive/active interchangeability), but she said "your example sentence is too difficult to discuss about that" Actually, your example sentence has a number of more basic errors, and she thought you needed to start with simpler sentences.

- 対比させる and 対比する are interchangeable in this context. See this similar question: [Difference between 完成させる and 完成する (transitive usage only)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27454/5010)
- に after 対比させる is the purpose marker (="to", "in order", "for").
- は after that is another topic/contrast marker. See: [Can we have two thematic は particles in a sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5375/5010)

Comment: If he's depending only on us and say google translate, the usage of 少し might be throwing him off ...