# Two は in a sentence

Tags: particle-は

From my Japanese book:

> この映画館で**は**、水曜日**は**１０００円で映画を見ることができます。

I wonder about these two は.

I think the first one (この映画館では) is a topic marker は and 水曜日は１０００円で[…] is a contrastive は (implying on the other days you cannot enter with 1000 yen)

Is this right?

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1130/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5375/9831

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in your analysis. The first は establishes the topic as この映画館で ("at this movie theater"). What came prior in the conversation was not talking about この映画館. Then, 水曜日は implies that the price is what it is on Wednesday, as compared to another day / other days when the price is something else (contrastive marker).

Answer (score 1):

Those two は do stress that "at this particular movie theater" and "on Wednesday" (not other days) you can watch movie for 1000 yen. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

`PLACE では` means "at PLACE", so its saying

```
At this movie theater, you can see a movie for 1,000 yen on Wednesdays.
```

It does imply that it isn't that price on other days, but that comes from the context and not the sentence structure itself. Its not strictly a contrastive, its just the standard subject marker.