# What does the とは mean in this phrase?

Tags: words, meaning

I'm pretty new to Japanese and I have a question.

So I know this is supposed to be something like "he differs from his former self" but I can't really make sense of what とは is supposed to mean in this particular situation:

> 彼は昔の彼とは違う

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a case of `は` acting as emphasis.  The `と` is used with `違う` to say that something is different than something else

> AはBと違う　→　A is different than/from B

Adding the `は` is placing the focus on the relationship (`彼` and `昔の彼`), not the analysis of the relationship (`違う`).

> - 彼は昔の彼と違う　→　He is different than his former self (neutral statement)
> - 彼は昔の彼とは違う　→　As for him and his former self, they differ

Fundamentally, they mean the same thing.  The difference is the focus.  Don't know if I'm explaining that well.  Take a look at this related question.  It does a good job explaining in-depth how adding `は` to another particle affects the meaning.

[What is the difference between “に” and “には”?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1096/78)