# は/が with いる. When to use each of them

Tags: particles

My textbook says the correct structure is

> WHEREにWHOがいる

For example:

> 日本にかおるさんがいる

But I've seen some webpages with examples such as:

> かおるさんは日本にいる

So... are they both correct? Do they have different meanings? Is one of them wrong?

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between “に” and “には”?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1096/78)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are correct but their meaning isn't exactly the same.

An easy way to understand it is to think of them as answers to different kind of question :

> 庭に犬がいる。
>
> (There is) a dog in the garden.

Can be the answer to :

> 庭に何がいる？
>
> What's in the garden?

Whereas :

> 犬は庭にいる。
>
> The dog is in the garden.

Can be the answer to :

> 犬はどこにいる？
>
> Where is the dog?

In the former example, the word precedeing が is the new information (which in this case can be translated with the indefinite article "a"), the hearer and the speaker both know which garden they are talking about.

**EDIT : This distinction between known and unknown information is probably 100% true when　に is followed by は (庭には...) but 庭に犬がいる can also mean "there is a dog in a garden" with both informations being new to the hearer.**

In the latter example, the word preceding は is the known information (translated with the definite article "the" here, they know which dog they are talking about), and the word preceding に is the new one.

So in your case :

> （誰が日本にいる？）日本にかおるさんがいる。
>
> (Who is in Japan?) (It is) Kaoru (that) is in Japan.

VS

> （かおるさんはどこにいる？）かおるさんは日本にいる。
>
> (Where is Kaoru?) Kaoru is in Japan.

You can find a similar construction with だ :

僕は学生だ。 (What are you?) I'm a student.

VS

僕が学生だ。 (Who is the student?) I'm the student.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.  Is the word order important? My book says that usually with ある／いる it's あそこにお酒がある, but I've seen in some places, for example, かおるさんは日本にいる

Comment: I think it's usually AにBがある and BはAにある but it's not mandatory.