# How to say "There is (A) in (B)(Location)."

Tags: particles, syntax, particle-は, particle-が

How do you say that there is a thing (e.g.: Restaurant ) in a certain place (e.g.: My town)? Is there a formula for this?

If someone were to ask me if there was a restaurant in my city they would say あなたの町に日本のレストランがありますか。

They would use the particle が but in my answer do I use は? And does that have to be in the beginning of the phrase or can I put it after the location (に particle)?

Comment: If a specific place is the topic then you can use [ Place + には ].

Comment: あなたの町に日本のレストランがありますか is not really a natural expression. It should be …日本料理のレストラン (or just  店) は ありますか. Using は is another point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For "There is a Japanese restaurant in my city", I'd say:

> 私の町**には**[日本食]{にほんしょく}のレストラン**が**あります。

［Place］には［Thing］があります。

("Japanese restaurant" can also be 日本食の[店]{みせ}、[日本料理]{にほんりょうり}のレストラン、日本料理の[店]{みせ}、[日本料理店]{にほんりょうりてん}、[和食]{わしょく}の[店]{みせ}、和食のレストラン, etc.)

For "Is there a Japanese restaurant in your town?", I'd say:

> あなたの町**に**日本食のレストラン**は**ありますか？

［Place］に［Thing］はありますか？

---

Addressing [this comment](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/43490/how-to-say-there-is-a-in-blocation/43502#comment80341_43493):

When asked 「あなたの町には何がありますか？」(What's in your town?), you'd reply:

> （私の町**には**）和食のレストラン**が**あります。

［Place］には［Thing］があります。

This is literally like "As for my town, a Japanese restaurant is there."
Use the topical は for old/known/given information, and が for new/important information.

When asked 「和食のレストランはどこにありますか？」(Where's a Japanese restaurant?), you'd reply:

> （和食のレストラン**は**）私の町**に**あります。

［Thing］は［Place］にあります。

This is literally like "As for a Japanese restaurant, there's one in my town."
Use the topical は for old/known/given information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are formulae.

First of all, you have to understand that `は` is a topic particle and particle `が` emphasis on what comes before it.

> Formula 1: Noun は Place に あります.
> Example : アメリカのレストラン は どこ に ありますか？
>
> Formula 2: Place には Noun が あります.
> Example : 東京 には アメリカのレストラン が あります.

**Usage of formula 1 and 2:**

> If a specific place is the topic >> use formula 2 (東京 には ~)
> If noun (you wanna talk about) is the topic >> use formula 1 (アメリカのレストラン は ~ )

Take a look at [Using location words with Subject/topic markers](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/28288/using-location-words-with-subject-topic-markers)
"Objects can also be the topic of a sentence (には, では, へは), but objects can't be the subject of a sentence"

Comment: Can you please clarify the diference between say: "アメリカのレストラン は東京に あります" And "東京 には アメリカのレストラン が あります"?

Comment: As I know they are almost same, formula 2 emphasis on "Specific place" as the topic. check **Usage of formula 1 and 2**