# Why is the particle omitted in this relative clause?

Tags: particles, relative-clauses

I am doing [this](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-lessons/japanese-grammar-exercises-relative-clauses/) exercise from wasabi-jpn.com. The exercise includes this sentence:

```
The sweater (I) bought last week was expensive.
```

Apparently, the correct answer is

```
先週買ったセーターは高かったです。
```

I realize that the particle は cannot be used after 先週 because it's a relative clause, but why there is no particle at all?

Comment: What particle were you thinking could go there?

Comment: @Leebo が. My thinking process was this: the full sentence would be 先週はセーターを買いました, so to make it a relative clause I need to change は to が. 
I also assumed that if が is incorrect than some other particle should be used, and I simply don't know the correct rule for this yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, using the particle が would make no sense at all. が marks the **subject** of a verb, so 先週**が**セーターを買いました would mean that "last week bought a jumper". Unless you have some bizarre world where you have anthropomorphised the weeks then this sentence is pure gibberish.

は and が are not interchangeable ([see this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/22/whats-the-difference-between-wa-%E3%81%AF-and-ga-%E3%81%8C)). は **can** mark a subject, but it does not do so in this case. The subject in this sentence is the hidden/implied "I".

Adding は to 先週 denotes that either 'last week' is the topic of the sentence, or that you are contrasting last week with some other time [see this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/28017/when-do-you-mark-%E3%81%8D%E3%82%87%E3%81%86-or-other-similar-relative-time-expressions-with-%E3%81%AF).

Finally, you are right that は is not normally allowed in a relative clause, but there is an exception. は can be retained if it is used as a contrast marker rather than as a topic (see [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/54689/%E3%81%AF-vs-%E3%81%8C-in-subordinate-clauses/54693#54693)).

In conclusion, no particle is needed in either the full sentence above or in the sentence which is just the relative clause.

Comment: I see. I got so used to seeing 先週は、今日は、明日は etc. in beginner lessons that I never questioned why exactly は was used here. This clears my confusion on all points. Thank you!