# 今 and the は particle

Tags: particles

I'm reading Genki I and I encountered the sentence 「今何時ですか。」 in page 42.

My question is: Why is the は particle not used after 今? Could we use it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When do you mark きょう or other similar relative time expressions with は](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/28017/when-do-you-mark-%e3%81%8d%e3%82%87%e3%81%86-or-other-similar-relative-time-expressions-with-%e3%81%af)

Comment: Yes you could use it, you could also drop it. In a lot of instances the は is omitted in speech, not only for time. Like instead of お前は何歳？ you could just say お前何歳？. It's always more formal to include the は though.