# Listing places in Japanese and using particles afterwards

Tags: particle-と, particle-で

If I want to say

> John studies **at** home **and** the library

do I say

> ジョンさんはうち**と**としょかん**で**べんきょうします。

I feel like I'm getting the particles wrong or that I'm actually supposed to use double particles.

Comment: Unmodified うち will be implicitly assumed to be "my home". You're recommended to use いえ or おうち (may sounds childish in this case) for "his home".

Answer (score 5):

> 「ジョンさんはうち**と**としょかん**で**べんきょうします。」

This sentence is grammatical but it does not sound very natural for a couple of reasons.

1) Use of 「うち」.  In this sentence, the speaker is NOT ジョン.  When native Japanese-speakers hear just 「うち」, we would tend to think it refers to the ***speaker's home*** as @broccoli forest states in the comment above.

To avoid that, you can use 「[自宅]{じたく}」 or 「[家]{いえ}」 instead of 「うち」.

2) Use of 「と」.  I am sure you just directly translated "and" and came up with 「と」.  As I said, it is grammatical, but the native speakers's word choice would be 「や」 considerably more often than 「と」.

If you think you are required to use 「と」 in your class, I will not beg you to use 「や」.

（「うち」, however, I must advise that you ***not*** use.）

Comment: Thank you for your helpful reply. If you don't mind, I have another question. In my class, we're learning about double particles yet I'm confused as to what では both means and when it is used. I figured では is used to mark both the subject and the location where an action is taking place but my professor provided examples where a は already marked the subject. Here's the example, たけしさんはとしょかんではべんきょうしますけど、りょうではべんきょうしません。I can't speak English in the class so that's why I ask here.

Comment: @flossboss That would be another question, but it's good to look in [this answer](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1130/7810) first.