# Need help with translation/grammar 「なんの」

Tags: grammar, translation, colloquial-language

I try to read a Japanese book, but I have some troubles with the following phrases which is part of a break up conversation:

「*俺はもう蕎麦屋には行かないから、千晶さんは安心して行っていいよ。*近所に住んでるし、ばったり会うこともあるかもしれないけど、まあ、気まず**くなんの**だけはやめような」

The part I have biggest difficulties with is the くなんの. I don't understand why the 気まずい is becoming an adverb and what function the なんの does exactly have. And also in the sentence before. It having 3x は's sounds a bit strange to me ... thanks a lot in advance for your help!!!!

Comment: Just curious why you selected oals's answer as correct when the focus of your post seemed to be the "なんの", not the triple は's. I purposely focused on the former, but if I misunderstood your focus I apologize.

Comment: I am sorry. I just realized I can only select one answer at correct. I read them at the same time and since you both helped me a great deal I wanted to give you both credit. Overlooked that you can't nominate more than one answer. I am sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, "なんの” is an abbreviation for "なるの”. There are other cases where る is abbreviated as ん, like in "ここにいんの？” (for "ここにいるの？”）.

Since "気まずい" means something like "become embarrassed" or "feel awkward", you could translate that portion as:

> まあ、気まずくなんのだけはやめような
>
> Well, at least try not too feel so awkward

Also, having multiple は's in a sentence is not necessarily a problem, and I don't think it is a problem in this sentence.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to cover the triple-は part of the question.

> 俺はもう蕎麦屋には行かないから、千晶さんは安心して行っていいよ。

The basic structure here is Sentence 1 から Sentence 2.

The first は marks the subject of the verb 行く

> 俺はもう行かない
>
> "I won't go any more"

The third は marks the subject that applies to the verbs 安心して行く

> 千晶さんは安心して行っていいよ
>
> "You can go [there] freely."

I consider these two cases trivial -- cases that your textbook taught when you first learnt to form sentences. The only thing slightly complex in this is that the subject changes (from 'I' to 'you') after the first clause, after から

---

The second は is the contrastive は

> 蕎麦屋には行かない
>
> "[I won't] go to the soba shop [but I may go elsewhere for my meal]

Some more discussion about the contrastive は [can be found in this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1096) and [here on why it tends to be used in negative sentences](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1077).