# は、には、に。。。what is the difference between them?

Tags: grammar

Can anyone explain the difference between the three sentences below and also the use of the grammar?

> 1. わたしのがっこう　は　日本人の　せんせい　が　います。
> 2. わたしのがっこう　に　日本人の　せんせい　が　います。
> 3. わたしのがっこう　には　日本人の　せんせい　が　います。

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1096/9749

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply speaking, for this example, は emphasizes the **topic** of the sentence,　に emphasizes the concept of **location**, and　には emphasizes the **location as the topic**.

Translating your three examples, which correspond to は,　に, and には, we get:

1. **On the topic of my school (がっこう　は),** there is a Japanese teacher.
2. **At my school (がっこう　に),** there is a Japanese teacher.
3. **On the topic of (the location that is) at my school (がっこう　には),** there is a Japanese teacher.

All three are grammatically correct, but have slightly different nuances to them.

Comment: Actually, が is a subject marker. When the same noun phrase is semantically both topic and subject, the が is 'hidden' by convention.  However I am not sure that is what is happening here.  There is already a が marked subject 先生が and 学校 feels like 'just' a topic, not a topic + 2nd subject.

Comment: @WeirdlyCheezy You are correct, I confused subject with topic. Editing answer to correct my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Grammatical explanation is this は in your sentence is a topic marker, this に is used as a postpositional particle which indicate place and this には is a compound word of に and は and this は is emphasis.

If you use は as a topic marker,  the meaning of the sentence 1 and 2 is almost same but if you can use は as contrast and emphasis, the sentence 1 and 3 have the meaning.

Comment: には can be simply topicalization of に, in short this は can be still a topic marker.

Comment: @user4092 The idea about this is always difference between I and you and we discussed about this before, so we don't need to discuss about this any more. And a dictionary say that. http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/167736/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF/

Comment: It looks like the information you are hoping to convey is useful, but the last sentence is a little confusing to me grammatically.  Would you be willing to give me a Japanese version of that sentence so I can confirm my understanding?

Comment: Yes. もし、"は"を話題の提示として使うなら、1と2の文はほぼ同じ意味となり、もし、"は"を対比と強調として使うなら、1と3の文は、その意味を持つ. Is my English wrong?

Comment: @YuuichiTam I wrote it for other users to read.

Comment: @ user4092 I think it is waste of time to discuss about this at all the time. You had better post your answer.

Comment: @YuuichiTam Sorry for the late response.  Your English is quite good, but there were a few ambiguities I wanted to double-check.  I would probably write:"The grammatical explanation is that the は in your sentences is a topic marker, the に is a post-positional particle which marks location, and the には is a compound of に and は where は is being used for emphasis.

If you use は as a topic marker,

Comment: ..accidental enter.   Last sentence continues:

If you use は as a topic marker, the meaning of sentences 1 and 2 is almost the same.   But, if you want to use は to contrast/emphasize, sentences 1 and 3 are possible examples of such usage."

Comment: @ WeirdlyCheezy Thank you for your suggestion.