# What is the difference between ni and ni wa, when talking about a person?

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between `ni` and `ni wa`, when talking about a person?

`Ni` has [many meanings](http://jisho.org/search/ni), but it is often used as [a marker for direction](http://www.punipunijapan.com/japanese-particle-ni-e/).
`Wa` is often used as a [topic marker](http://www.punipunijapan.com/japanese-particles-wa-ga/).

In my textbook, it has the following example:

```
Kanojo ni wa takusan no keiken ga arimasu.
She has plenty of experience
```

Why is `ni wa`, used for `Kanojo` (she). How can you have a person as a direction?

There is also this:

```
Kouhosha erabi ni wa motto sentakushi ga aru beki dato omoimasu.
I think there should be more choice in candidates
```

Again, ni wa is used for `Kouhosha erabi` (Candidate selection). Again, how can you have people as direction?

[This answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/what-is-the-difference-between-%E3%81%AB-and-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF) for a similar question, says that `ni wa` helps to indicate an embedded subject, but I don’t understand how that differs from plain `wa` on it’s own, and what is gained by using `ni wa`.

Would the above examples sentences be wrong if they omitted ni? 
If not, then what does ni add to the meaning?
What is the rule for when to use `ni wa` in place of `wa`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why do you try to stick to only one definition of *ni* when you already know [it has many meanings](http://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%AB)?

> Kanojo ni wa takusan no keiken ga arimasu.
>   彼女にはたくさんの経験があります。
>
> (lit.) In her, there is much experience.
>   → She has a lot of experience.

Here に is used as a place marker. Think of it as "within her" or "in her", and it's actually no different from the 図書館 example you linked. It's the first definition of jisho.org.

> Kouhosha erabi ni wa motto sentakushi ga aru beki dato omoimasu.
>   候補者選びにはもっと選択肢があるべきだと思います。
>
> For choosing a candidate, I think there should be more choices.

Here に is used to mark a purpose, and it's the third definition of jisho.org. 候補者選び is a noun phrase which literally means "candidate-choosing". A simpler example for this に is 買い物**に**出かける (="go out *for* shopping").

And these は after に are topic markers, which indicate what they are talking about. I don't know how I can explain this better when you are already seeing good explanations.

Can we omit に or は in these sentences? Without these は, these sentences will look fairly awkward. Presenting a topic is important.

Whether you can drop に before は depends on the sentence. You can safely drop the に without changing the meaning in your second example:

> 候補者選びはもっと選択肢があるべきだと思います。

This would be closer to "Regarding candidate-choosing, ..." than "For candidate-choosing, ..." but it still makes sense. You can drop に in your first example, too, but it would make the sentence slightly awkward.

Sometimes dropping に can drastically change the meaning of the sentence:

> - 彼には感謝しています。 I am grateful to him.
> - 彼は感謝しています。 He is grateful (to someone).

Comment: I think I was struggling with the concept of experience being a place, (as in English experience is not normally associated with a location) but from your explanation (of it being “within her”), that now makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 0):

I like to think of ni as an all purpose location marker, location of information, location of destination, location of existence, location of receiver, even location of intent, (kaimono o shi ni iku・買い物をしにいく)