# Changing を to は in negative statements

Tags: grammar, meaning, particles, particle-は, particle-を

I've got confused and have a few questions:

In some situations speaker is obligated to change the particle e.g. answering yes/no questions.

> Question: あなたはくじ**に**ひこうきにのりますか。(A)
>
> Answer: いいえ、わたしはくじ **には** ひこうきにのりません。じゅうじにのります。(B)

But what if I do not answer any question?
I can simply say:

> 本をたくさん読みます。(C)

Is it grammatically correct?

The verb here is 読み (read).
Read what? > A book = 本 = direct object
Who read? > I read = わたし = subject (implied)

1.) Is it correct to say:

> 本はたくさん読みます。(D)

In this situation we will have two は in one sentence:

> (わたしは)本はたくさん読みます。(E)

Is this situation OK?
Isn't it confusing for the person who is a receiver of this statement?

2.) Do we have to change を to は in negative statements?

Or is it correct to say:

> 本をたくさん読みません。 (F)

Or should it be:

> 本はたくさん読みません。 (G)

3.) How do we exactly understand statements F and G?

Do the particles have impact on meaning here?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1130/32315) talks a bit about the にand には differences. I think a good distinction to make is that には, とは and such should be treated as special particles - you can't really just combine particles willy-nilly.

As for the other sentences, the は in D, G and E don't really make sense (at least to me), mainly because a sentence can't really have two subjects. So C is the best.

Now this extends to the negative sentences as well. In your examples you'd still use を.

Also, the use of たくさん doesn't really make sense in a negative sentence. Instead you should say "not much" or あまり.

> 本をあまり読みません。

Finally, just an extra note. You can use 本は by making 読む a passive verb.

> 本は読まれました。

( The book was read. )

Hope this helps!

Comment: ehh i'm not so sure about some points of your answer, I see the pattern: "(ommited personal pronoun) Object + は + verb" a lot... I can even remember this quote from the top of my head: 「(私は)手助けはしない！」. Unfortunately I don't know the exact grammar to answer this, though.

Comment: That's fair enough - the rules of any language are made to be broken. Searching for that particular phrase yields quite a few results on forums and casual / social channels. But returns nothing on ejje.weblio.jp. From this I'd assume it's more of an exception than the rule.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, both E, G make sense to me, but one condition.
本は読まない sounds that you are implying reading something else, like manga.
But you're expected to explain the alternative after that.
Let's say you have habits (A,B,C,E) but the speaker just asks you "Dをしますか？", you probably say "Dはしません でもAはしますよ". 
It's equal to say "I don't do D but I do A" which is the same category to the question.
So 本はたくさん読みません tells you don't just read books but you wanna say that you have another thing that you do a lot.